# MySQL: Join with 4 tables and common field: row_number()

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables -

Tab: d

```
Name | ID 
----------
A    | 1
B    | 2
C    | 3
```

Tab: p

```
Name | ID 
----------
AX   | 1
B    | 2
X    | 3
Y    | 4
Z    | 5
```

Tab: s

```
Name | ID 
----------
A    | 1
BL   | 2
V    | 3
M    | 4
```

Tab: a

```
Name | ID 
----------
K    | 1
J    | 2
H    | 3
N    | 4
```

Now I am using MySQL and today I found out that MySQL does not support FULL join. So, I am using left join with all 4tables and then using "union" and right join to merge all the 4 tables' records.
The query I am using is like -

```
(select d.Name, p.Name, s.Name, a.Name from doc d 
left join
prof p
on d.id = p.id
left join
sing s
on d.id = s.id
left join
act a
on d.id = a.id)
union
(select d.Name, p.Name, s.Name, a.Name from doc d 
right join
prof p
on d.id = p.id
right join
sing s
on d.id = s.id
right join
act a
on d.id = a.id)
```

But this is not giving the intended output. It is giving something like -

```
D    |    P    |   S    |    A
---------------------------------
A    |    AX   |   A    |    K     
B    |    B    |   BL   |    J
C    |    X    |   V    |    H
NULL |    NULL |   NULL |    N
```

Actual output should be -

```
D    |    P    |   S    |    A
---------------------------------
A    |    AX   |   A    |    K     
B    |    B    |   BL   |    J
C    |    X    |   V    |    H
NULL |    Y    |   M    |    N
NULL |    Z    |   NULL |    NULL
```

Please help me to figure out what I am missing! And also to help me to get the result...

Comment: just a clue on how to make it much easier: `select * from d,p,s,a;`

Comment: @FlashThunder _No_, _never_ put commas in the from clause if you can avoid it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why not, it's much faster than join (in syntax and in computing time)

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you really want here is a full outer join, but MySQL does not directly support that (and the workaround is fairly ugly).  One approach I can suggest here would be to maintain a fifth table containing all `ID` values which you expect in the result set.  Consider:

```
SELECT c.ID, d.Name, p.Name, s.Name, a.Name
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) c
LEFT JOIN d ON d.ID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN p ON p.ID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN s ON s.ID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN a ON a.ID = c.ID
ORDER BY c.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! But I want to make the query little bit generalized not specific to the sample I mentioned here. Creation of your ID table (temporary) and hardcoding 5 entries are making the query a bit tougher to implement. Can you come up with something little more generic.

Comment: @AmitavaChowdhury I disagree, and my answer is the way to go here.  A _general_ solution to simulate a full outer join in MySQL between 4 tables is going to be very ugly and hard to maintain code.  You should get a fifth table which maintains all the IDs, then just left join out to the various tables you displayed above.

Comment: But Tim! For that I need to know maximum number of ID to be maintained in the ID temp table and manually writing the query to select that number of IDs from the temp table! I am worried for this reason only...

Comment: @AmitavaChowdhury Right, that's what I suggest maintaining a _table_ with these IDs.  By the way, having the need to do such a full outer join here indicates poor database design.  There should be _one_ master table with all IDs in your system.  In these other tables, the `ID` should be a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using MySQL v8, you might be able to do it this way:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS rn, MAX(cnt) AS mxcnt 
  FROM
  ( SELECT COUNT(ID) cnt FROM doc UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM prof UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM sing UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM act ) v UNION ALL
SELECT rn+1, mxcnt FROM cte WHERE rn+1 <= mxcnt)

SELECT c.rn, d.Name, p.Name, s.Name, a.Name
  FROM cte c 
  LEFT JOIN doc d ON d.ID = c.rn
  LEFT JOIN prof p ON p.ID = c.rn
  LEFT JOIN sing s ON s.ID = c.rn
  LEFT JOIN act a ON a.ID = c.rn
ORDER BY c.rn;
```

Using `WITH RECURSIVE` to generate numbering sequence based on the largest count result from all related table then use it as the reference in `LEFT JOIN`. I agree with Tim about having a master table for all of the ids.